# Is there way for a GWT program to tell if it's in hosted or web mode?

Tags: java, gwt

I would like my GWT program to be able to determine whether it's in hosted mode or in web mode.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GWT.isScript() returns true in non hosted mode and false in hosted mode.

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html#isScript()

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with this.  You still can't run unemulated Java code in the statement.

```
if(GWT.isScript()) {
  //some code not in the JRE emulation here
}
```

The example code will cause compile time problems.