# how to tell different modes in gwt 2.0

Tags: gwt

Anyone know how to tell what mode an GWT 2.0 app is currently running at?

The idea is that i could do something like:

```
if(GWT.whatIsYourmode() == 'dev')
  //run some code
else
  //run some different code
```

Comment: We had that already I guess: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223373/is-there-way-for-a-gwt-program-to-tell-if-its-in-hosted-or-web-mode. So `GWT.isScript()` returns false if the app runs in hosted mode.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're looking for is `GWT.isClient()`, `GWT.isProdMode()` or `GWT.isScript().` You can find the [Javadoc here](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html#isClient%28%29).